# Read from file or stdin

Tags: c, file, io, stream, stdin

I am writing a utility which accepts either a filename, or reads from stdin.

I would like to know the most robust / fastest way of checking to see if stdin exists (data is being piped to the program) and if so reading that data in.  If it doesn't exist, the processing will take place on the filename given.  I have tried using the following the test for size of `stdin` but I believe since it's a stream and not an actual file, it's not working as I suspected it would and it's always printing `-1`.  I know I could always read the input 1 character at a time while != EOF but I would like a more generic solution so I could end up with either a fd or a FILE* if stdin exists so the rest of the program will function seamlessly.  I would also like to be able to know its size, pending the stream has been closed by the previous program.

```
long getSizeOfInput(FILE *input){
  long retvalue = 0;
  fseek(input, 0L, SEEK_END);
  retvalue = ftell(input);
  fseek(input, 0L, SEEK_SET);
  return retvalue;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("Size of stdin: %ld\n", getSizeOfInput(stdin));
  exit(0);
}
```

Terminal:

```
$ echo "hi!" | myprog
Size of stdin: -1
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, ask the program to tell you what is wrong by checking the `errno`, which is set on failure, such as during `fseek` or `ftell`.

Others (tonio & LatinSuD) have explained the mistake with handling stdin versus checking for a filename. Namely, first check `argc` (argument count) to see if there are any command line parameters specified `if (argc > 1)`, treating `-` as a special case meaning `stdin`.

If no parameters are specified, then assume input is (going) to come from `stdin`, which is a **stream** not file, and the `fseek` function fails on it.

In the case of a stream, where you cannot use file-on-disk oriented library functions (i.e. `fseek` and `ftell`), you simply have to count the number of bytes read (including trailing newline characters) until receiving **EOF** (end-of-file).

For usage with large files you could speed it up by using `fgets` to a char array for more efficient reading of the bytes in a (text) file. For a binary file you need to use `fopen(const char* filename, "rb")` and use `fread` instead of `fgetc/fgets`.

You could also check the for `feof(stdin)` / `ferror(stdin)` when using the byte-counting method to detect any errors when reading from a stream.

The sample below should be C99 compliant and portable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

long getSizeOfInput(FILE *input){
   long retvalue = 0;
   int c;

   if (input != stdin) {
      if (-1 == fseek(input, 0L, SEEK_END)) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Error seek end: %s\n", strerror(errno));
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      if (-1 == (retvalue = ftell(input))) {
         fprintf(stderr, "ftell failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      if (-1 == fseek(input, 0L, SEEK_SET)) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Error seek start: %s\n", strerror(errno));
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
   } else {
      /* for stdin, we need to read in the entire stream until EOF */
      while (EOF != (c = fgetc(input))) {
         retvalue++;
      }
   }

   return retvalue;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   FILE *input;

   if (argc > 1) {
      if(!strcmp(argv[1],"-")) {
         input = stdin;
      } else {
         input = fopen(argv[1],"r");
         if (NULL == input) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open '%s': %s\n",
                  argv[1], strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
         }
      }
   } else {
      input = stdin;
   }

   printf("Size of file: %ld\n", getSizeOfInput(input));

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 26):

You're thinking it wrong.

What you are trying to do:

*If stdin exists use it, else check whether the user supplied a filename.*

What you should be doing instead:

*If the user supplies a filename, then use the filename. Else use stdin.*

You cannot know the total length of an incoming stream unless you read it all and keep it buffered. You just cannot seek backwards into pipes. This is a limitation of how pipes work. Pipes are not suitable for all tasks and sometimes intermediate files are required.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to look at how this is done in the `cat` utility, for example.

See code [here](http://nxr.netbsd.org/source/xref/src/bin/cat/cat.c#raw_args).
If there is no filename as argument, or it is "-", then `stdin` is used for input.
`stdin` will be there, even if no data is pushed to it (but then, your read call may wait forever).

Comment: Note that you can use `cat fileA - fileB` to surround the standard input with the contents of `fileA` and `fileB`.  It is not limited to being the only argument.  With some programs (such as `paste`), you can use `-` multiple times (sometimes including `cat`, sometimes even usefully).  For example, `paste - - -` creates 3 columns of output from the data read from standard input, reading one line for the first column, another for the second, and a third line for the third column.

Answer (score 5):

You can just read from stdin unless the user supply a filename ?

If not, treat the special "filename" `-` as meaning "read from stdin". The user would have to start the program like `cat file | myprogram -` if he wants to pipe data to it, and `myprogam file` if he wants it to read from a file.

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[] ) {
  FILE *input;
  if(argc != 2) {
     usage();
     return 1;
   }
   if(!strcmp(argv[1],"-")) {
     input = stdin;
    } else {
      input = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
      //check for errors
    }
```

If you're on *nix, you can check whether stdin is a fifo:

```
 struct stat st_info;
 if(fstat(0,&st_info) != 0)
   //error
  }
  if(S_ISFIFO(st_info.st_mode)) {
     //stdin is a pipe
  }
```

Though that won't handle the user doing `myprogram <file`

You can also check if stdin is a terminal/console

```
if(isatty(0)) {
  //stdin is a terminal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just testing for end of file with `feof` would do, I think.

Comment: `feof` is tricky since it requires you to have made a prior attempt to read from the stream and failed. (And if you do that, you might as well check failure reason.) It's not obvious how you propose using it for this situation either.

Answer (score 0):

Note that what you want is to know if stdin is connected to a terminal or not, not if it exists. It always exists but when you use the shell to pipe something into it or read a file, it is not connected to a terminal.

You can check that a file descriptor is connected to a terminal via the termios.h functions:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool stdin_is_a_pipe(void)
{
    struct termios t;
    return (tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &t) < 0);
}
```

This will try to fetch the terminal attributes of stdin. If it is not connected to a pipe, it is attached to a tty and the tcgetattr function call will succeed. In order to detect a pipe, we check for tcgetattr failure.

Comment: had to add #include <unistd.h> to get STDIN_FILENO defined