# Stdin doesn't work when I run the program

Tags: c, terminal

I have the following C code in code.c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *openFile = NULL;
    openFile=stdin;
}
```

but when I compile and run my code with

```
gcc -g -o compiledcode code.c
./compiledcode
```

the terminal doesn't prompt me for an input. What is wrong?

Comment: Is that all your code?

Comment: Welcome (back) to Stack Overflow.  Please reread the [Ask] page, and even more urgently, read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  What you've provided is too minimal to be useful.  We can only assume that the second line is inside a function; the first might be inside or outside a function.  There's not enough information to know what else is going wrong.

Comment: Yes, that is all my code inside main. I will edit it to show the main function now

Comment: You aren't prompting the user for any input, nor are you trying to read any input.  All you've done is set the file stream pointer `openFile` to point to standard input; you've never read anything (or written anything).  I note in passing that since you are not using the command line arguments, you should write `int main(void)` in preference to `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.

Comment: Okay, so how can I ask  for input using stdin?

Comment: You can use `printf()` to print the prompt to standard output, and you could use `scanf()` or `fscanf()` or `getchar()` or `getc()` or any of the other input functions to get input.  Please consult your textbook; this sort of stuff tends to be covered quite early.

Comment: For reference, I was following this post, which seems like it worked for them?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495092/read-from-file-or-stdin

Comment: Don't have a textbook, got any recommendations?

Comment: Were you following the question or the answer(s)?  The question code fails,  The accepted answer code uses `fgetc()` — one of the other input functions I didn't mention — to get data.

Comment: I'd recommend King [C Programming: A Modern Approach (2nd Edition)](http://knking.com/books/c2/index.html) from the books listed at [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  It seems to do a competent job.  The classic is K&R, but that is now rather dated (the second edition describes C90, and was published just before the original C standard was finalized).  It's still a good (compact) book, but it shows its age.

Comment: go it,  thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You just open stdin as file but you don't read your file.
There are many different ways to get input from stdin.

Function `getchar` can be used to read a single character from stdin.  Use `getc()` or `fgetc()` to read from an arbitrary file stream.
Example:

```
int c = getchar();
printf("you entered %c\n", c);
```

Function `fgets` can be used to read a line from file.
Example:

```
char data[200];
fgets(data, sizeof(data), stdin); // we type stdin as file.
printf("you entered %s\n", data);
```

Function `scanf` and its family of functions can be used to read many different formats from stdin.
example:

```
char data[200]; // size need be bigger or equal to input length
scanf("%199s", data);  // Protect from buffer overflow
printf("you entered %s\n", data);
```

Comment: You should NEVER use gets. Use fgets() instead. Is a more safer function.